# How to iterate through a list with each click returning to the initial value?

Tags: javascript

The code below is an outline of what I need:

```
<div></div>
<button>Click</button>


var list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var obj = document.querySelector('div');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    obj.textContent = list[0];//execute only on the first click
    obj.textContent = list[1];//execute only on the second click
    obj.textContent = list[2];//execute only on the third click
});
```

With each click, each item in the list must be shown in the `div`. When the `c` value is displayed, the next click should display the `a` value and so on.

That is, the output in the `div` must be:
`a`
`b`
`c`
`a`
`b`
infinitely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of the current position in the array, then go back to zero when you reached the end. Here's a very simple implementation of the logic

```
var list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var pos = 0;
var obj = document.querySelector('div');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    obj.textContent = list[pos];
    pos++
    if(pos >= list.length) {
        pos = 0
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use a function generator

```js
const list = ['a','b','c']

function* tabGen(tab) {
  let i = 0
    , max = tab.length
    ;
  while (true) {
    yield tab[i++]
    i %= max
  }
}

const onTab = tabGen( list )

theButton.onclick = () => { 
  theDiv.textContent = onTab.next().value 
}
```

```html
<div id="theDiv">..</div>
<button id="theButton"> button </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var obj = document.querySelector('div');
var i = 2;
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(i+1 > 3){ i = 0}
    obj.textContent = list[i]
    i++
});
```

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

JAV - Just Another Version - because people type faster than me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"/>
<title> Test Page </title>
<!-- From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67757162/how-to-iterate-through-a-list-with-each-click-returning-to-the-initial-value -->
<style>
</style>

</head><body>
<div id="counter"></div>
<button id="btnCounter" data-cnt="0">Click</button>

<script>
var list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
document.getElementById('btnCounter').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let btnID = document.getElementById('btnCounter');
  let currentCount = +btnID.getAttribute('data-cnt');
//  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = list[currentCount];      //     single display
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML += `${list[currentCount]} `; //     alternate display
  currentCount = ((currentCount + 1) % 3);
  btnID.setAttribute('data-cnt',currentCount);
});

</script>

</body></html>
```